# What is Text-based API option in Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, build-settings

Recently, I observed section named **Text-based API** in Xcode build settings. In Xcode 7.X it's under **Linking section**. But now with Xcode 8.X, it's separated out as another section in Xcode build settings. I'm interested to know what exactly it will do?

Image for reference:

[image]

Answer (score -5):

From Xcode 8.0 and above version, Text-based API is in Build setting as it have different business logic